# Access a second router from a first one

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a first router which is connected to the line and receives the internet signals then I have cables (RJ45) to connect to other computers, a switch as well as wifi.
I have a second router connected to the first one with an RJ45 cable to have wifi on a remote zone.

- Router 1 has a fixed IP `192.168.1.1`
- Router 2 has a fixed IP `192.168.2.1`

I managed twice to enter the page of the second router, but I want to add a password to the wifi and I am unable to enter again.
I can enter the page of the first router from the second router and from the first router.

When I try to access the first router page from a computer to the first one or directly connected to the second one, the page does not load.
Also, the only time I managed to connect to router 2, was disconnecting the cable between the two routers.
Now, when this cable is disconnected I am unable to connect via wifi with the laptop. But I can connect with the tablet. But with the tablet also I cannot access router 2 page.

How can I do it?

Comment: Typically, if you setup router 1 (connected to internet) as 192.168.1.1, you set Router 2 as 192.168.1.2, disable DHCP, setup the wireless the same  but on a different channel, andnnect a LAN port from R1 to a LAN port in R2. In this configuration R2 is just a switch & AP and R1 does all the work. Otherwise you will need to do a bit more work and port forwarding.

Comment: The second router already had the IP set to 190.168.2.1 automatically and was fixed. Yes, I disabled DHCP. I will have to look into setting up the wireless on a different channel, but the problem now is that I cannot access router 2. When I do a search for the ip, it is the router one IP that comes up. Wireless is working fine, just it does not have a password.

Comment: it needs to be 192.168.1.2 (or something in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet), since it's 192.168.2.1 it is in a different subnet, this not reachable. Remember, on R2 you will not use the WAN/Internet port.

Comment: OK, I guess I will have to reset it? But last time I checked it, the IP was grayed out, IE, not changable...

Comment: Possible... On both routers? It doesn't matter which one has which IP address, as long as they don't conflict and are within the same subnet. R1 can be 192.168.1.2 and R2 can be 192.168.1.1, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I saw the IP grayed out in R2, in R1 I can change it. Endereços IP


Endereço IP/máscara IPv4 Tipo 



192.168.1.1/24 Estático 


192.168.1.254/24 Estático 


192.168.1.253 Partilha de
conteúdos

Comment: What are the routers manufacturers and specific models?

Comment: I saw the IP grayed out in R2, in R1 I can change it. 

The IP info on R1 is as follows:
Endereços IP 192.168.1.1/24 Estático 
Endereço IP/máscara IPv4 192.168.1.254/24 Estático  
192.168.1.253 Partilha de conteúdos
What is the /24 on the first line?

Comment: /24 denotes CIDR notation, meaning the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. /23 would denote 255.255.254.0, /16 would be 255.255.0.0, /28 would be 255.255.255.240. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: I'm sorry, but the translation of those numbers doesn't make sense... I understand the terms, but not what these things mean as they seem to conflict. "IP addresses 192.168.1.1/24 Static IPv4 address / mask 192.168.1.254/24 Static 192.168.1.253 Sharing of content" Are you saying that R1 is now 192.168.1.254? If so, that will work fine, just disable DHCP on R2 and connect two of the LAN ports together, you should be able to get to the Internet and access both routers since there is no longer a conflict.